# Club data in a data table into a single row based on a condition in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I need to club data in a datatable into a single row based on a condition in my c# page

For example

[image]

In this table i have different rows but the last three rows have the same date. I need to have the data in the table to be combined by date

ie in the rows having same date the data in the other columns have to be added like the image below

[image]

My datatable contains very huge amounts of data so can you help in solving this in less no of iterations??

Comment: you could use this query:Select orderdate,sum(quantitysold),sum(taxamount),sum(amount) from tablename group by orderdate.

Comment: @ShoaibMuhammadKhan I need to do this in c# not in sql. So i don't need a sql query

Comment: You need to club data? As in clubbing baby seals?

Comment: i didn't get you Mr.CodeCoaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by doing this. The post of Bjorn helped me.

```
var drdatedisp = from row in dtfullreport.AsEnumerable()
                  group row by row.Field<string>("Order_Date") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Order_Date = g.Key,
                      totalAmt = g.Sum(a => a.Field<int>("Item_Quantity"))

                  };
 DataTable dtdatedisp = new DataTable();
 dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Order_Date");
 dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Quantity");
 dtdatedisp.Rows.Clear();
 foreach (var g in drdatedisp)
 {
     DataRow newRow1 = dtdatedisp.NewRow();
     newRow1[0] = g.Order_Date;
     newRow1[1] = g.totalAmt;
     dtdatedisp.Rows.Add(newRow1);
 }
```

also I added the data from the variables to a datatable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use linq to achieve this, I wrote a small case which you could modify a little to fit your situation:

```
    var list = new List<Model>();

    list.Add(new Model { Date = DateTime.Now, Total = 3 });
    list.Add(new Model { Date = DateTime.Now, Total = 3 });
    list.Add(new Model { Date = DateTime.Now, Total = 3 });

    var combined = from item in list
                   group item by new { item.Date, item.Total }
                   into grouped
                   select new Model
                       {
                           Date = grouped.Key.Date,
                           Total = grouped.Sum(i => i.Total)
                       };
```

The `Model`is your model, which has the data as displayed in your table. Basically you do a group on all field you need to be the same. Then you would create a new `IEnumerable' which is filled with the grouped entries. Here you can use the date from the group-key, and you can sum the other values.

-- EDIT

To get everything directly added as rows into a `DataTable` you could do something like this:

```
        var list = new List<Model>();

        list.Add(new Model { Date = DateTime.Today, Total = 3 });
        list.Add(new Model { Date = DateTime.Today, Total = 3 });
        list.Add(new Model { Date = DateTime.Today, Total = 3 });

        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Date");
        table.Columns.Add("Total");

        foreach (var grouped in from item in list
                                group item by new { item.Date, item.Total }
                                    into grouped
                                    select grouped)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(grouped.Key.Date, grouped.Sum(i => i.Total));
        }
```

Comment: How to get valuws from var combined into a datatable??

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I included a snippet for inserting the rows in a DataTable.

Comment: Thank you I got the answer and I posted it